# Splitting input stream in to multiple windows and process individually

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Datastream . I have to apply window function as 1 hour, 2 hour, 3 hour...24 hour. And each split has its own window function to be done

How do I split the window in an efficient way.

The dirtiest way I can think of is

```
for(int i=1; i < 24 ;i++){
   inputStream.keyBy("id").timeWindow(Time.hours(i)).apply(..);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure to have understood what you really want. You want to have different windowing at the same time in a parallel way, right ?

Comment: Single stream, different window , different time interval, parallely

Comment: This is an interesting question. What you proposed obviously work, you could make 24 different window proccesing. However, I can't believe a better way is not possible. Depending on your window function, could you use the 1 hour windowing ouput for your 2 hour windowing and so on ? I mean, the 2 hour windowing might be the merge of two successive 1 hour windowing.

Comment: @madhairsilence I would like to know if you have find a good solution or not, it is an interesting question

Comment: I could not find a better solution. I had to change my actual logic

Answer (score 1):

More efficient would be to implement a custom trigger based on EventTimeTrigger (assuming you're working with event time, otherwise ProcessingTimeTrigger) that fires every hour.